# How to make footer in Linear Layout in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to make footer in linear layout but this layout I also use fragment tag. Does anyone how to set a footer in this layout? I have seen many examples but I found no success.

My XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.ListFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.DetailFragment" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/filter"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buy_now"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clear_all"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am new in android developing please me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use another LinearLayout to act as footer, a footer refer only to a listview.

Comment: can you give a example

Comment: Did you really need an example of creating a linearLayout on xml, you have posted an example of that!

Comment: Can't Understand what you asking. Please describe clearly first.

Comment: Or post Image of your requirement.

Comment: From what I can tell, your 'footer' is actually more of a 'sidebar'

Comment: I need a footer in this layout i given above

Comment: Not only `fill_parent` is deprecated. If you want a FIXED footer, you better use a RelativeLayout as the root container. And, please, flatten your layout!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your XML.

Let me know is that your requirement?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.ListFragment" >
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detail_Fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.DetailFragment" >
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buy_now"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Clear All"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now In fragment where you don't need footer you can set visibility as GONE or INVISIBLE using that "android:id="@+id/footer""

Comment: can you tell me how to align right side of  android:text="@string/filter"

Comment: Check the edit. You can now set Gravity as per your requirement. I have set it in center

Comment: TextViews in the footer: if you're using layout_weight, either layout_width or  layout_height should be 0dp (which one is not known since you are also missing orientation in the footer's LinearLayout)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you're doing with those layout_weights in your fragments but this should get you close to what you want (I'm assuming you want those two fragments showing side-by-side?):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
      class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.ListFragment" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/detail_Fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
           class="shoppingmazza.android.catalyst.com.shoppingmazza.activity.DetailFragment" />

    </LinearLayout

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/filter"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/buy_now"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clear_all"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```